# Getting rid of a thin framing line when shading a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I am trying to draw a shaded triangle with tikz, using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[top color=green!40,middle color=white,shading angle=45]  (-2.5,-3) -- (12.5,3) -- (-2.5,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think it is hard to see in the image posted below, but just along the diagonal is a very thin line. Is there any way to get rid of this line?

This is with Tikz/PGF version 2.10.

[image: tikz compiled image]

Comment: you can find out your pgf version by putting a ``\listfiles`` command into the preamble of your document. This will write all invoked packages and classes as well as their version into the log file.

Comment: I think you should try with `\draw[top color=green!40,middle color=white,shading angle=45,draw=none]  (-2.5,-3) -- (12.5,3) -- (-2.5,3) -- cycle;`. Does it fix the problem?

Comment: If this is going to be some sort of a header use the whole page not the triangle itself.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, yes, this works well.

Comment: @BenediktBauer, thanks, I updated the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\shade` instead of `\fill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[top color=green!40,middle color=white,shading angle=45]  (-2.5,-3) -- (12.5,3) -- (-2.5,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by Paul replacing `\fill` by `\path` would also work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[top color=green!40,middle color=white,shading angle=45]  (-2.5,-3) -- (12.5,3) -- (-2.5,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PaulGaborit The thing is so complex and I have trouble understanding your comment/objection `:-)` Can you shed some more light on it? You may feel free to edit the answer itself, if you feel appropriate. I appreciate your effort. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not to use or not to use `\shade` (`top color` always selects the shade option). The problem is to mix it with a fill operation. A simple `\path` instead of `\fill` is sufficient.